# Physics for a towed bar

Tags: matlab, physics, game-physics

I am trying to implement a rigid bar which is pulled from one end, in Matlab. The initial coordinates of the points are P1(1,0) P2(0,0).

I am using lumped mass model, where the weight is on the particles. The only existing efforts are a vertical effort in P1 and the gravity. The mass of each particle is 0.05.

My code is shown next:

```
L=1; %length of the bar

Mass1=[1 0; 0 1];
Efforts1=[0; 20-9.8*0.05];

Mass2=[1 0; 0 1];
Efforts2=[0; -9.8*0.05];

acel1=Mass1\Efforts1;

acel2=Mass2\Efforts2;
dt=0.1; %time step


%variables creation
position of mass1
x1=zeros(100,1); x1(1)=L; x1(2)=L; 
y1=zeros(100,1); 
%position of mass2
x2=zeros(100,1); 
y2=zeros(100,1);
%velocities 
x1_dot=zeros(100,1); y1_dot=zeros(100,1);
x2_dot=zeros(100,1); y2_dot=zeros(100,1);

for i=2:100
   %numerical integration of first mass. Accel, vel, pos
   x1_dot(i)=x1_dot(i-1) + dt*acel1(1);
   y1_dot(i)=y1_dot(i-1) + dt*acel1(2);

   x1(i)=x1(i-1) + dt*x1_dot(i);
   y1(i)=y1(i-1) + dt*y1_dot(i);

   %numerical integration of first mass. Accel, vel, pos
   x2_dot(i)=x2_dot(i-1) + dt*acel2(1);
   y2_dot(i)=y2_dot(i-1) + dt*acel2(2);

   x2(i)=x2(i-1) + dt*x2_dot(i);
   y2(i)=y2(i-1) + dt*y2_dot(i);

   if y2(i)<0
       y2(i)=0;
   end

   X=[x1 x2]; Y=[y1 y2];
   plot(X,Y); hold on;
   pause(0.1);

 end
```

The problem can be represented in next figure:

[image: lumped mass model]

Considering that two masses are not damped and behave as a solid bar (constant length), how can I model the coupling effect so that the P2 mass follows correctly P1 under gravity?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the problem. In your code the point with its coordinates stored in `x1` and `y1` is actually P2(1,0) and on this point a vertical force is applied. The point with its coordinates stored in `x2` and `y2` is actually P2(0,0) and it is vertical fixed. Is my understanding right? Maybe the problem is not well composed since it is only fixed in vertical direction which can lead to some problems in the horizontal movement.

At the moment you apply a force on P2 and you calculate the movement/displacement of P2. This movement is however not coupled to P1. If you want to calculate the "coupled" movement you have to take into account internal forces. This can be done with the Hooks Law for 1D rods.

Does this help you?

Micha

Comment: I corrected some mistakes in the statement and added a picture so that I can make myself clearer

Comment: thank you for the figure. If you want to the physics of this system you should use, as mentioned, the Hooks Law and internal forces. There you will see that it is impossible to have L = 1 after a certain time with the current boundary conditions.

A different approach is to adapt the displacement of point P1 and P2 after the integration in order to meet the requirement of L = 1. This approach however is not related to physics and may give you completely wrong results even so L = 1 will remain ok.